# PDB: Download all biological assemblies

Tags: protein-structure, pdb

I was wondering if it is possible to download all biological assemblies from the PDB at once (so not the standard asymmetrical files). For example, I want a file containing the coordinates of all atoms in a trimer, instead of only the coordinates of a monomer.

I saw that you can batch download with a shell script, but I'm not sure if you can also do that for biological assemblies.

Comment: Alternatively, you could download a "standard" file from the PDB (either in the PDB format or in mmCIF) and generate assemblies locally with one of many programs/toolkits have such capability.

Comment: I'm not aware of a program/toolkit with which you can do that automatically for a large set of PDB files. If you know of a way to do that then that would be perfect.

Comment: To process multiple files you will probably need a simple script. Note that PDB entries often define several alternative biological assemblies. As for toolkits, I'm most familiar with gemmi (because I maintain it): you could generate assemblies from the command-line with [gemmi convert --assembly=1 ...](https://gemmi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html#convert) or from [Python](https://gemmi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mol.html#assembly). I suppose that BioJava, cctbx, PyMOL, etc also have such a capability.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the wwPDB ftp site https://ftp.wwpdb.org/ in your browser you can find the biological unit structures (and anything else available in the PDB). The caveat of course is that a biounit structure has to have been generated for your structure.

By way of some examples, to get all biological units you could do (note the `ftp` instead of `https` in front of the URL):

```
wget ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/biounit/PDB/all/*
```

or to get a version organized in directories:

```
wget ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/biounit/PDB/divided/*
```

Note that this would take a few days to download everything, though. After the first download, you can add a `-N` to the `wget` command to just download new files.

For getting just one file:

```
wget ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/biounit/PDB/divided/00/100d.pdb1.gz
```

Hope this helps.